# ffmpeg normalization waveform

Tags: ffmpeg, normalization, waveform

Im creating waveform's to my audio player by code:

```
ffmpeg -i source.wav -filter_complex "aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwavespic=s=1280x90:colors=#000000" -frames:v 1 output.png
```

Sometimes waveform looking so bad like here:

[image]

Sometime in other song looking good like here:

[image]

So first waveform is tiny.. How can I normalize scale output waveform to size of output image 90px height?

Comment: ffmpeg is graphing the average sample value in each window. The bar height has to accommodate the maximum possible value.

Comment: But I belive it is possible to draw waveform where maxiumum possible value is like height of image (90px) not smaller

Answer (score 0):

There's a command you can add called "compand" which scales the waveform vertically. You could update your ffmpeg command to be:

```
ffmpeg -i source.wav -filter_complex "compand,aformat=channel_layouts=mono,showwavespic=s=1280x90:colors=#000000" -frames:v 1 output.png
```

You can check out the documentation here: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform